# Apache Echarts - Use Multiple Datasets On A Single Series

Tags: echarts

Is it possible to apply a visual encoding to a series that uses a separate dataset?  Use case as follows:

1. Dataset encoded as a TypedArray (int16) that contains x, y positions for a scatter plot.
2. Dataset encoded as a TypedArray (uint8) that contains color values.  The user may elect to change dataset 2 to color by a different feature.

The obvious solution would be to merge the two datasets client side as (x,y,color,x,y,color,...), but would like to avoid duplicating the datasets in memory and the overhead associated with the transform.  I see many examples of reusing a dataset across multiple series, but not applying multiple datasets to a single series.

Thank you!